# Facebook application icon not showing up in links

Tags: facebook, icons, hyperlink

I have developed my first facebook application, and I have uploaded the thumbnails and icons for it [image]. However when I'm linking my application or posting it to someone's wall, the icon appears as if I didn't upload it.

[image]

My question is if this image should be inside my PHP api code or do I have to upload it from my facebook app page?

Comment: are you using the same icon on your website, and have you added it on your app?

Comment: I didn't use any icon on my website. I thought this is only related to the facebook application, since I'm sharing the link inside facebook. I've also tried some meta tags with the icons in it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Seems there was a problem with facebook cache, so I used the [debugging tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and now whenever I share the link, my thumbnail is showing up. I didn't have to do anything inside the code, only on the facebook app UI.